# pick observation or row having longer name in sas

Tags: sas

i have dataset a like this

```
id   name          age sex
1  Murray, W       23   M
2  Bonaventure, T  24   F
3  Eberhardt, S    56   M
4  LaMance, K      78   M
5  Underwood, K    23   F
```

we have to create dataset b from dataset a

```
id   name          age sex
2  Bonaventure, T  24   F
```

we have to select data having longer name in all name variable so we have to select the observation having longer name so dataset b contain only one data.

Comment: Is this some kind of test/training exercise? The answer is rather obvious using the `length()` function. This is not even a very SAS specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find first the maximun length across all records and then compare it against each indiviual record's length. bear in mind that more than one record can meet this criteria. in your example is only one though.

Here is a solution using `proc sql`

```
proc sql;
create table b as 
select * from a 
    where
        length(name) = (select max(length(name) from a) ;
quit;
```

Comment: pls accept answer if you think answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possibilities you can do it. 
Here you have example how to obtain a correct result using only one data step.

```
data b;
    retain max obs 0;

    set a end=last;

    if lengthn(name) > max then do;
        max = lengthn(name);
        obs = _N_;
    end;

    if last;
    set a point=obs;
    drop max obs;
run;
```