# find maximum observation length in a column in sas

Tags: sas

i have dataset a like this

```
id   name          age sex
1  Murray, W       23   M
2  Bonaventure, T  24   F
3  Eberhardt, S    56   M
4  LaMance, K      78   M
5  Underwood, K    23   F
```

we have to create dataset b from dataset a

```
id   name          age sex
2  Bonaventure, T  24   F
```

we have to select data having longer name in all name variable so we have to select the observation having longer name so dataset b contain only one data.using max & length function only

i am trying this code

```
data d;
set a;
max_name=length(name);
run;

data max;
set d;
m=max(max_name);
run;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pick observation or row having longer name in sas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892740/pick-observation-or-row-having-longer-name-in-sas)

Comment: What do you want to do when there is more than one observation with the maximum length?

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of possibilities you can do it. Here you have example how to obtain a correct result using only one data step.

```
data b;
    retain max obs 0;

    set a end=last;

    if lengthn(name) > max then do;
        max = lengthn(name);
        obs = _N_;
    end;

    if last;
    set a point=obs;
    drop max obs;
run;
```